# getline() is only reading second word (bug)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that reads in a name and prints it back out. I want to use `getline` so it will read the entire line, so the name can have any number of words in it. (That is why I don't want to just use `cin` twice.)  But it is only printing the second word. What is wrong with it?

Input: `Rock Lee`

Output: `Lee`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    string name;

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cout.flush();
    cin >> name;

    getline(cin, name, '\n');


    if (name == "")
    {
        cout << "Name is blank.";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << name;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cin >> name;
```

reads "Rock" from the input stream and safes it in `name`. The stream now contains " Lee\n". Now

```
getline(cin, name, '\n');
```

reads the remaining " Lee\n" from the stream, discards the `\n` and then overwrites `name` with the result. `name` now contains " Lee".

To read the whole line into `name`, remove the `cin` line that "steals" the first word.

Btw, the `cout.flush();` is not necessary since `cout` and `cin` are tied by default, i.e. `cout` will always be flushed when control reaches a `cin`.